# Install Ubuntu-Server do I need UEFI?

Tags: server, system-installation, uefi

My pc does not have uefi-bios. Can I install ubuntu server 15.10 without trouble?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need UEFI for any Ubuntu version at the moment. Might even be problematic with really old be versions.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a bit on Jakob's (correct) answer, the industry is moving toward EFI/UEFI, but the transition is far from complete. Ubuntu supports both BIOS-mode and EFI-mode booting, so either should work if the server supports both, and if the server is BIOS-only, you should still be fine, and should remain fine for the foreseeable future.

I personally recommend EFI-mode booting in most cases if the computer supports both, at least in most cases. (As Jakob suggests, some early EFI implementations were extremely bugggy and so might work better in BIOS mode; but most such problems have been fixed on new hardware.) This is, of course, a moot point if the computer lacks EFI support.